# Array_walk average with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, average

I have an array and I want to make the average of its array element.

```
$array = array(
               '1' => array('1', '2'), 
               '2' => array('3', '7'), 
               '3' => array('5', '6'));

function average($arr)
    { if (!is_array($arr)) return false;
    return array_sum($arr)/count($arr); }

array_walk($array, 'average');
print_r($array);
```

The problem is that my function is not applied by array_walk. I got the exact same array I declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function average($elem){
   return array_sum($elem)/sizeof($elem);
}               
$arr = array_map('average',$array);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/107661)

Comment: Short, quick, working well and a live demo. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the values from average function but not receiving it anywhere, if you wana change the multidimensional arrays values to their sum do this:

```
function average(&$arr)//&
{ 
    if (!is_array($arr)) return false;
    $arr = array_sum($arr)/count($arr); 
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution and the result is the same